# Somar Valores de Uma Linha da Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia, galera!

Eu tenho uma table que é preenchida com os dados de um XML, e cada linha da tabela tem os input quantidade, valor unitário, ipi e total. Então gostaria que ao editar uma informação na linha o sistema calcula-se o Total Produto ref. a linha alterada. Segue a tabela abaixo para entender melhor, preciso usar javascript para isso.

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Produto</th>
        <th>Quantidade</th>
        <th>Valor Unit.</th>
        <th>IPI</th>
        <th>Total Produto</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Telha Cimento</td>
        <td><input type="txt" id="quantidade" name="quantidade" value="10"></td>
        <td><input type="txt" id="valor-unit" name="valor-unit" value="150,00"></td>
        <td><input type="txt" id="valor-ipi" name="valor-ipi" value="85,90"></td>
        <td><input type="txt" id="valor-total" name="valor-total" value="2.359,00"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bloco de Vidro</td>
        <td><input type="txt" id="quantidade" name="quantidade" value="5"></td>
        <td><input type="txt" id="valor-unit" name="valor-unit" value="55,00"></td>
        <td><input type="txt" id="valor-ipi" name="valor-ipi" value="10,90"></td>
        <td><input type="txt" id="valor-total" name="valor-total" value="329,50"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Não precisas e jQuery para isso. Basicamente:

- escuta o evento `input` em cada `tr`
- extrai os elementos
- faz a conta tendo em conta que `,` em JavaScript deve ser `.`
- formata o total com o locale

> **Nota:** não podes ter IDs repetidos na mesma página. Esses IDs de cada input devem ser removidos...

```js
const trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
trs.forEach(tr => {
  tr.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const [quantidade, valorUnit, valorIpi, valorTotal] = tr.querySelectorAll('input');
    const total = Number(quantidade.value) * Number(valorUnit.value.replace(/,/, '.'));
    valorTotal.value = total.toLocaleString();
  });
});
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Produto</th>
    <th>Quantidade</th>
    <th>Valor Unit.</th>
    <th>IPI</th>
    <th>Total Produto</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Telha Cimento</td>
    <td><input type="txt" id="quantidade" name="quantidade" value="10"></td>
    <td><input type="txt" id="valor-unit" name="valor-unit" value="150,00"></td>
    <td><input type="txt" id="valor-ipi" name="valor-ipi" value="85,90"></td>
    <td><input type="txt" id="valor-total" name="valor-total" value="2.359,00"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bloco de Vidro</td>
    <td><input type="txt" id="quantidade" name="quantidade" value="5"></td>
    <td><input type="txt" id="valor-unit" name="valor-unit" value="55,00"></td>
    <td><input type="txt" id="valor-ipi" name="valor-ipi" value="10,90"></td>
    <td><input type="txt" id="valor-total" name="valor-total" value="329,50"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Não sabia bem o que fazer com valorUnit, valorIpi... por isso omiti o valorIpi na conta. Mas isso é simples de corrigir.

Comment: Posso sugerir não gerar novos arrays a partir do retorno do método `querySelectorAll`? Não tem o porque nesse caso, o retorno do querySelectorAll já é um objeto que possui o método iterador (Symbol.iterator), e também seu próprio método `forEach`.

Comment: @user140828 verdade, hábitos antigos, corrigi.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção usando jQuery e formatando o resultado com duas casas decimais é usando no resultado do cálculo:

```
.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "decimal", minimumFractionDigits: "2"})
```

Crie um escutador de eventos `input` para cada campo input e busque os valores dos inputs na linha inteira pelo atributo `name` (remova os id's repetidos, até porque eles não são necessários).

Como o JavaScript calcula decimais separados por ponto, é necessário remover primeiramente os pontos que separam as casas de milhar e em seguida substituir a vírgula que separa as decimais por ponto:

```
.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')
```

Depois multiplicar o valor da quantidade pelo valor do produto e somar com o IPI. Veja que coloquei `|| 0` nos valores para evitar `NaN` caso um campo de algum valor esteja vazio, assumindo o valor `0` se estiver vazio.

Repare também que usei `parseFloat` apenas no valor do IPI, já que ele é o único valor que será somado, caso contrário o valor seria concatenado. Os outros que serão multiplicados não precisam de conversão.

Ao fazer o cálculo dos campos, jogar o resultado para o último campo com `name='valor-total'`.

Ficará assim:

```js
$(function(){
   
   $("td input").on("input", function(){
      
      var linha = $(this).closest("tr");
      var quantidade = $("[name='quantidade']", linha).val();
      var unidade = $("[name='valor-unit']", linha).val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.') || 0;
      var ipi = parseFloat($("[name='valor-ipi']", linha).val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')) || 0;
      var calc = quantidade*unidade+ipi;
      $("[name='valor-total']", linha).val(calc.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "decimal", minimumFractionDigits: "2"}));
   });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Produto</th>
        <th>Quantidade</th>
        <th>Valor Unit.</th>
        <th>IPI</th>
        <th>Total Produto</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Telha Cimento</td>
        <td><input type="txt" name="quantidade" value="10"></td>
        <td><input type="txt" name="valor-unit" value="150,00"></td>
        <td><input type="txt" name="valor-ipi" value="85,90"></td>
        <td><input type="txt" name="valor-total" value="2.359,00"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bloco de Vidro</td>
        <td><input type="txt" name="quantidade" value="5"></td>
        <td><input type="txt" name="valor-unit" value="55,00"></td>
        <td><input type="txt" name="valor-ipi" value="10,90"></td>
        <td><input type="txt" name="valor-total" value="329,50"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```